# Write the permutation as product of cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations

Let the permutation
$$\sigma=\bigl(\begin{smallmatrix}
1 & 2 &3  &4  &5  &6  & 7 &8  & 9 & 10\\ 
 3& 4 & 5 &6  & 7 & 2 & 1 & 10 & 9 & 8
\end{smallmatrix}\bigr)$$

Analyze $\sigma$ as a product of disjoint cycles and calculate its order in $S_{10}$. Is $\sigma$ even or odd?

$$$$

I have done the following:

$$\sigma=(1 \ \ 3 \ \ 5 \ \ 7) \ (2 \ \ 4 \ \ 6) \ (8 \ \ 10)$$
$$ord{(\sigma)}=LCM(4, 3, 2)=12$$
$$\text{ Since } \sigma \text{ is written as a product of } 3 \text{ circles, }\sigma \text{ is odd. }$$

$$$$

Could you tell me if this is correct??

Comment: Do you mean *disjoint cycle* instead of *foreign circle*?

Comment: Oh yes...I will edit my post...

Comment: Then you are entirely correct.

Comment: Great!!! Thank you!!! :-)

Comment: Well, no @MaryStar: your permutation is *not* odd but even, since it is a product of two odd cycles (the 2 and 4 cycles) and one even cycle (the 3 cycle)...

Comment: @DonAntonio I got stuck right now.. Do I have to check what type of circle is each one? So the first one $( 1 \ \ 3 \ \ 5 \ \ 7 )$ has $4$ elemets, so it's even, the second one $(2 \ \ 4 \ \ 6)$ has three elements, so it's odd and the third one $(8 \ \ 10)$ has two elements, so it's even. So we have (even) * (odd) * (even)=(even)? Is it correct? And why does it stand that: (even) * (odd) * (even)=(even) ?

Comment: Hi @MaryStar. First, stop writing "circles": it is **cycles** . Second, yes: you *must* check each cycle, remembering that a cycle is an **even permutation** iff its length is **odd**, and the other way around. Thus, the cycle $\;(1\;2\;3\;4)\;$ is **odd** since its length (4) is even, and thus your whole permutation is odd.even.odd = even.

Comment: I understand!!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to prove that a cycle is even iff its lenght is odd is to write it as a product of transpositions, knowing that a transposition is odd ( **always** ):

$$\sigma:=(i_1\;i_2\;...i_k)=(i_1\;i_2)(i_2\;i_3)\cdot\ldots\cdot(i_{k-1}\;i_k)$$

As you can see, the cycle $\;\sigma\;$ is the product of $\;k-1\;$ transpositions, and thus (Syg:= sygnum = sign) :

$$Syg(\sigma)=(-1)^{k-1}=\begin{cases}\;\;\,1&,\;\;\;k\;\;\;\text{is odd}\\{}\\-1&,\;\;\;k\;\;\;\text{is even}\end{cases}$$